# Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduling

I need to write a spring boot application which has REST services as well as a scheduler.

My Maven POM has the following dependencies

```
spring-boot-starter
spring-boot-starter-test
spring-boot-starter-web
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
```

My Main Application with REST working perfectly. But When add a Scheduler it gave me

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
```

---

```
@Configuration    
@EnableAutoConfiguration  
@ComponentScan   

public class ServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {   

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
        SpringApplication.run(MyTasks.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ServiceApplication.class);
    }
}
```

And here is my Scheduler class

```
@EnableScheduling
public class MyTasks {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 50)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        System.out.println("MyTasks : The time is now " + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

Can we do both REST and scheduling from same spring boot application. I have tested both seperately but both are working

Comment: How about to `@EnableScheduling` to the main config with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`?

Comment: I move the @EnableScheduling to main. But still the same issue

Comment: It works for me with Embedded Tomcat. Tested with Spring Boot 1.2.0.